# consolidate a list by value and date

Tags: python

I have a `sql query` result set which I need to transpose to suit a charting application.

```
[(1, '2017-01-01', 2), 
 (1, '2017-02-01', 4),
 (1, '2017-03-01', 6), 
 (1, '2017-04-01', 8), 
 (2, '2017-01-01', 20),
 (2, '2017-02-01', 40),
 (2, '2017-03-01', 60),
 (2, '2017-04-01', 80),
 (3, '2017-01-01', -1),
 (3, '2017-02-01', -2),
 (3, '2017-03-01', -3),
 (3, '2017-04-01', -4)]
```

I need

```
[('2017-01-01', 2, 20, -1), 
 ('2017-02-01', 4, 40, -2),
 ('2017-03-01', 6, 60, -3), 
 ('2017-04-01', 8, 80, -4)]
```

Consolidating by the date and store each value relative to the value of first column

Being new to `python` I cant quite work out the best method, I suspect `list comprehension` may be suitable for this.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I'd use an `OrderedDict`, so you can access each list by its date directly:

```
import collections

result = [(1, '2017-01-01', 2), (1, '2017-02-01', 4), (1, '2017-03-01', 6), (1, '2017-04-01', 8), (2, '2017-01-01', 20), (2, '2017-02-01', 40), (2, '2017-03-01', 60), (2, '2017-04-01', 80), (3, '2017-01-01', -1), (3, '2017-02-01', -2), (3, '2017-03-01', -3), (3, '2017-04-01', -4)]

d = collections.OrderedDict()

for tup in result:
    key = tup[1]
    d.setdefault(key,[]).append(tup[2])
```

Result:

```
print(d)
OrderedDict([('2017-01-01', [2, 20, -1]), ('2017-02-01', [4, 40, -2]), ('2017-03-01', [6, 60, -3]), ('2017-04-01', [8, 80, -4])])
```

Where `d['2017-01-01']` would return `[2, 20, -1]`, etc.

If you really need that list structure, you can actually build it from the dict created:

```
final_result = []

for k,v in d.items():
    final_result.append(tuple([k]+v))
```

Result:

```
print(final_result)
[('2017-01-01', 2, 20, -1), ('2017-02-01', 4, 40, -2), ('2017-03-01', 6, 60, -3), ('2017-04-01', 8, 80, -4)]
```

You can also do that second step as a list comprehension:

```
[tuple([k]+v) for k,v in d.items()]
```

Here is a Jython implementation (it's slower algorithmically, but should still serve your purpose):

```
result = [(1, '2017-01-01', 2), (1, '2017-02-01', 4), (1, '2017-03-01', 6), (1, '2017-04-01', 8), (2, '2017-01-01', 20), (2, '2017-02-01', 40), (2, '2017-03-01', 60), (2, '2017-04-01', 80), (3, '2017-01-01', -1), (3, '2017-02-01', -2), (3, '2017-03-01', -3), (3, '2017-04-01', -4)]

final_result = []

for tup in result:
    tup_added = False
    for current_list in final_result:
        if current_list[0] == tup[1]:
            current_list.append(tup[2])
            tup_added = True
            break
    if not tup_added:
        final_result.append([tup[1], tup[2]])

final_result = [tuple(x) for x in final_result]

print(final_result)
```

Comment: `d.setdefault(key,[]).append()` is what i would recommend but yeah

Comment: Did not know you could do that, and I've been coding in Python for half a decade... Cool!

Comment: A better way to go :)

Comment: Thanks very much that's looks perfect - but I suspect my system using Jython 2.5.3 doesn't have OrderedDict available based on error "object has no attribute 'OrderedDict'.

Comment: Ah, you probably should have tagged your question with `Jython`. Regardless, `OrderedDict` is not part of Jython or Python until 2.7. You could replace it with a non-ordered dict (`d = {}`), but you will lose the order of the tuples.

Comment: Yes noted, my apologies for not making that apparent. I can live with the un-ordered tuples as the charting application will sort that out. Thank you very much for your great solution and your valuable time !

Comment: All good - I've also added a Jython compatible ordered version if you'd prefer that.

Answer (score 2):

Try with `groupby` from `itertools` :

```
from itertools import groupby

result = []
sub_result= []
for key, group in groupby(a_list, lambda x: x[1]):
    sub_result.append(key)
    for g in group:
        sub_result.append(g[2])
    result.append(tuple(sub_result))
    sub_result = []
print result
```

Output:

```
[('2017-01-01', -1, 2, 20), ('2017-02-01', -2, 4, 40), ('2017-03-01', -3, 6, 60), ('2017-04-01', -4, 8, 80)]
```